# What does the degree of a polynomial have to do with the finite extension of a body?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let L : K be a finite extension, and let p be an irreducible polynomial over K.
Show that if op and [L : K] are coprime, .then p has no zeros in L .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474059/degree-of-irreducible-polynomial-and-field-extension-are-coprime).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "op" you mean deg($p$) (maybe this is notation I'm unfamiliar with) assume $\theta \in L$ is a root of $p$ and consider the field tower $K \subset K(\theta) \subset L$, can you get a contradiction based on the degrees of these extensions ?